# Uploading Image to database in php & ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to upload an `image` to database from html page in a form in a `modal` through php & ajax,but it doesn't work i don't know why,anyone can help me?

**HTML Page**

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <label class="Modallabel">Photo:</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <div class="input-group input-group-sm" style="margin-top: -5px;">
            <input type="file" id="fileUpload" name="fileUpload" style="color: #ffffff;"/>
        </div><br>
      </div>
    </div>
</form>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-md" style="margin:0;width: 75px;" onclick="AddNewCustomer()">Add</button>
```

**Javascript Function**

```
function AddNewCustomer()
{
//Image upload
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $(document).on('change', '#fileUpload', function() //NOT WORKING HERE
    {
        var property = document.getElementById("fileUpload").files[0];
        var image_name = property.name;
        var image_extension = image_name.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
        if (jQuery.inArray(image_extension, ['gif','png','jpg','jpeg']) == -1)
        {
            alert("invalid Image File");
        }
        var image_size = property.size;
        if(image_size > 2000000)
        {
            alert("Image File Size is very big");
        }
        else
        {
            var form_data = new FormData();
            form_data.append("fileUpload", property);

            $.ajax
            ({
                type:"POST",
                url:"addNewCustomer.php",
                processData: false,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                data:
                    {
                    'form_data':form_data
                    },
                success: function(data){
                    if (data == "Success!")
                    {
                        sweetAlert("Data entered successfully!");
                    }
                    else if(data == "Exist") 
                    {
                        sweetAlert("","Customer already exists!","error");
                        return false;
                    }
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log('ERROR', textStatus, errorThrown);
                }
            })
        }
    })
})

}
```

Comment: *doesn't work* is not enough to understand what is going on , 2nd: where is your php code?

Comment: it means that the code doesn't enter to run the next code between parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

`change` event would be attached after click at `<button>` at `onclick="AddNewCustomer()`.

You can remove `AddNewCustomer` function and call `change` on `#fileUpload` element at click of `.btn` element.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('change', '#fileUpload', function() {//do stuff})

  $(".btn").on("click", function() {
    $("#fileUpload").trigger("change");
  });
});
```

Comment: The form has another inputs (First Name,Last Name,Email,...Photo) that's why i have to have the function `AddNewCustomer`

Comment: @NewDeveloper What is purpose of `click` event at `.btn` element?

Comment: The purpose is to add the customer data in the database(Name,Phone,Emai,....Photo)

Comment: @NewDeveloper Does approach at Answer not produce expected result?

Answer (score 0):

You want to upload the image immediately after it's chosen, but you only run the function when the 'Add' button is clicked.

You need to take your `change` code out of the function, or invoke the function when the page is loaded to add the listeners to the form.